# importing a component in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, import, components, vuejs3

Hi I'm trying to import a component in Vue 3.
This is my component structure :

```js
+src
  +App.vue
  +components
    +Navbar.vue
```

In my App.vue I tried :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
<div>
<Navbar/>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import  Navbar  from './components/Navbar.vue';
</script>
```

This is my main.ts :

```html
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from './router'

import mitt from 'mitt';
const emitter = mitt();

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue-3/dist/bootstrap-vue-3.css'
import BootstrapVue3 from 'bootstrap-vue-3'
import App from './App.vue'
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.use(BootstrapVue3)
app.mount('#app')
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter;
```

But I get this error :

```js
Already included file name '/home/jip/Projects/snippedit/client/src/components/Navbar.vue' differs from file name '/home/jip/Projects/snippedit/client/src/components/navBar.vue' only in casing.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via './components/Navbar.vue' from file '/home/jip/Projects/snippedit/client/src/App.vue'
    Root file specified for compilation
    Root file specified for compilation
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The import should be inside the `<script setup>` section

Comment: I tried that didn't help.

Comment: What is the content of your `main.js`? Normally, you do not import `vue.js` in a component, but in `main.js`

Comment: I added it to my post.

Comment: `main.js` looks good. Did you try without the first `<script>` tag in `App.vue`?

Comment: You have 2 `<script>` tags in your App.vue - the first one should be inside `<template>` or not there at all.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean could you post an answer I will vote for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how `App.vue` should look like:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <Navbar />
   </div>
</template>

<script setup>
   import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `vuter` extension try restarting/reloading vscode